# Adding styles to a new feature in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, features, coding-style

I am new to Google Earth Engine and JavaScript. I have created a dropdown box and a button. The dropdown contains sub-district names from a shapefile. After clicking the button, the selected place is shown in the map as a polygon.

```
var subDist= table.aggregate_array('admin3Name');
var subDistDD= ui.Select([],'Loading...');
subDist.evaluate(function(sD){
  subDistDD.items().reset(sD);
  subDistDD.setPlaceholder('Select a Place');

});
var btnShow=ui.Button('Go To Place');
btnShow.onClick(function(){
  var placeName=subDistDD.getValue();
  var selectedSubdist=ee.Feature(table.filterMetadata('admin3Name','equals',placeName).first())
  .set({style: {fillColor: '00000000'}});
  Map.addLayer(selectedSubdist.style({styleProperty: "style"}));
  Map.centerObject(selectedSubdist,12);
});
var panel=ui.Panel({
  widgets:[subDistDD,btnShow],
  style: {width:'210px', resize:'horizontal'}
});
ui.root.insert(0, panel);
```

The program runs without error. But when the place is selected and the button is clicked, an error shows up: `selectedSubdist.style is not a function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selectedSubdist` is a Feature, `style()` is a function on FeatureCollection.  Wrap it in a FeatureCollection wrapper.

```
ee.FeatureCollection([selectedSubdist]).style({styleProperty: "style"})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I had to assign the FeatureCollection to another variable. Then add it as a layer.